# Least Exactly Problem

Tags: combinatorics

I read following problem and solution:

> In a recent test of $100$ students,
>
> - $95$ answered question #1 correctly
> - $75$ answered question #2 correctly
> - $97$ answered question #3 correctly
> - $95$ answered question #4 correctly
> - $96$ answered question #5 correctly
>
> What is the smallest number of students who could have answered exactly $4$ of the $5$ questions correctly?

The solution is:

A maximum of $75$ could have answered all questions correctly. Of the remaining $25$, the $5$ who got question #1 wrong, the $3$ who got the question #3 wrong, the $5$ who got question #4 wrong and the $4$ who got question #5 wrong could have been uniquely different giving $17$ who got exactly $3$ questions correct. This leaves $8$ who got exactly $4$ questions correct.

My question:

1. What maths topic/book is this problem involved?
2. Is "uniquely different" a term? (it looks like $5 + 3 + 5 + 4 = 17$, but what does it mean? Or why it means who got exactly $3$ questions correct?)
3. Why the "least exactly $4$" problem is $8$ ($25 - 17 = 8$)?
4. As an extension, What is the smallest number of students who could have answered exactly $1/5, 2/5, 5/5$ questions correctly?

Thank you in advance. M

Comment: Personally, I am unsure whether this problem would be classified as Combinatorics, Number Theory, or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood this problem now: place 5 sticks.

given 5 sticks, whose length is 25, 5, 3, 5, 4.

Here I will list 3 "extreme" cases, and the answer is obvious.

```
                                     111...(58)...111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

case 1: If you put all the sticks on the ground one after another, then the length is 25+5+3+5+4 = 42, which is the LARGEST number of students who got only 1 wrong. (In other words, all the other 100-42 = 58 students get all questions correct)

```
                         111...(75)...111
0000000000000000000000000
00000
00000
0000
000
```

case 2: If you put all the sticks align at one side, then it means: 3 students(column 1~3) get all 5 questions wrong; 1(column 4) students get exactly 4 questions wrong; 1(column 5) students get exactly 3 questions wrong; 20 students get exactly 1 questions wrong; 75 students get all questions correct.

```
                         111...(75)...111
0000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

case 3: If you put stick 5, 3, 5, 4 one after another and align the head with stick 25, then: 5 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 17 students get exactly 2 questions wrong; 25 - 17 = 8 get 1 questions wrong.

The answer is the case #3.
Unique different means no intersection :)

Comment: Since no other people post answers this question, I will accept my own answer. If in the future there are better ones, I will change the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse it:

- 5 got #1 wrong
- 25 got #2 wrong
- 3 got #3 wrong
- 5 got #4 wrong
- 4 got #5 wrong

What is the smallest number of students that only got 1 question wrong.

Imagine:

- If there were only question `#1` and `#2`, each have 5 students got wrong with

  - The largest number would be the union `5+5`, meaning no overlap, i.e. no students got both wrong

[image]

- The smallest number would be 0, meaning complete overlap, i.e. all 5 students got both wrong

[image]

- If `#1 = 5` and `#2 = 10`

  - The largest number, still union, `5+10`
    [image]
  - The smallest, within the `10` who got `#2` wrong, you can remove 5 that also got `#5` wrong (the overlap), leaving you with 5 that only got `#2` wrong
    [image]
- The intuition is: make them overlap as much as possible, so what left is the smallest number of student that got exactly 1 question wrong
- When there are more than 2 questions, the same logic still applies, make them overlap with the largest number and remove them from the larger number
  [image]
- Since they only overlap with the largest number and was then removed, meaning everyone's got only `#2` and exactly one single other question wrong, everyone was uniquely removed, i.e. no one was removed because one got wrong a third question wrong, otherwise it wouldn't be the smallest number of students

[image]

- If the smaller numbers cannot be uniquely removed from the largest numbers (e.g. `8`, `9`, `10`  students got `#1`, `#2`, `#3` wrong respectively) then the smallest number of students who got exactly 1 right would be 0

Answer (score -2):

How I see it: the number of students getting exactly 4 questions right $(E_4)$ is embedded in the number of students getting at least 3 questions right $(A_3)$. Let $E_i$ be the number of students getting exactly i questions right.
$E_4 = A_3-E_3-E_5$ and the maximal values of $A_3, E_5$ are 100 and 75 respectively and the corresponding maximal value of $E_3$ would be 17. Hence, the smallest value $A_4$ can take is 8.